# Oracle order by unexpected result

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by

I have this query :

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
ID_USER, 
NUMERO, -- VARCHAR2(8 BYTE) 
NOM
FROM USER_VIEW 
WHERE UPPER(NOM) = 'JACKSON'
ORDER BY NUMERO ASC
```

I expect results to be like this :

```
ID_USER  |   NUMERO   |   NOM
--------------------------------
1        |   TI33     |  JACKSON
9        |   TI99     |  JACKSON
4        |   1999     |  JACKSON
0        |   2001     |  JACKSON
3        |   2006     |  JACKSON
8        |   *04      |  JACKSON
5        |   *15      |  JACKSON
7        |   *61      |  JACKSON
```

but I'm getting unwanted results :

```
ID_USER  |   NUMERO   |   NOM
--------------------------------
1        |   TI33     |  JACKSON
9        |   TI99     |  JACKSON
8        |   *04      |  JACKSON
5        |   *15      |  JACKSON
4        |   1999     |  JACKSON
0        |   2001     |  JACKSON
3        |   2006     |  JACKSON
7        |   *61      |  JACKSON
```

Can somebody explain why I'm getting these results ? and how can I fix this?

Comment: which data type is numero ??

Comment: Apparently, in whatever collation the `numero` column is defined to be, `*` isn't considered a meaningful character for sorting purposes.

Comment: Yes I looks like the '*' is ignored in sorting. How can I still get the desired result?

Comment: Can you add your session NLS settings to the question just for background - at least `NLS_SORT` and `NLS_COMP`, but maybe also `NLS_TERRITORY` and `NLS_LANGUAGE`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be using [linguistic sorting and matching](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/nlspg/linguistic-sorting-and-matching.html), and whatever `NLS_SORT` is set to in your session - or possibly a [column-level collation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/nlspg/linguistic-sorting-and-matching.html#GUID-2AC4EE67-D3C0-4E26-87AD-2DA4584F874A) setting - is causing you to encounter [ignorable characters](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/nlspg/linguistic-sorting-and-matching.html#GUID-4801B9FC-976F-458E-B74F-F39817B79560).

With my default session I don't see the same as you:

```
alter session set nls_sort = binary;
alter session set nls_comp = binary;

with user_view (id_user, numero, nom) as (
  select 1, cast('TI33' as varchar2(8 byte)), 'JACKSON' from dual
  union all select 9, 'TI99', 'JACKSON' from dual
  union all select 4, '1999', 'JACKSON' from dual
  union all select 0, '2001', 'JACKSON' from dual
  union all select 3, '2006', 'JACKSON' from dual
  union all select 8, '*04', 'JACKSON' from dual
  union all select 5, '*15', 'JACKSON' from dual
  union all select 7, '*61', 'JACKSON' from dual
)
SELECT DISTINCT 
ID_USER, 
NUMERO,
NOM
FROM USER_VIEW 
WHERE UPPER(NOM) = 'JACKSON'
ORDER BY NUMERO ASC
/

   ID_USER NUMERO   NOM    
---------- -------- -------
         8 *04      JACKSON
         5 *15      JACKSON
         7 *61      JACKSON
         4 1999     JACKSON
         0 2001     JACKSON
         3 2006     JACKSON
         1 TI33     JACKSON
         9 TI99     JACKSON
```

If I change the settings (picking a language at random) then I do:

```
alter session set nls_sort = spanish_ci;
alter session set nls_comp = linguistic;

...

   ID_USER NUMERO   NOM    
---------- -------- -------
         1 TI33     JACKSON
         9 TI99     JACKSON
         8 *04      JACKSON
         5 *15      JACKSON
         4 1999     JACKSON
         0 2001     JACKSON
         3 2006     JACKSON
         7 *61      JACKSON
```

You can change the session, or override the sort for just that column using the `nlssort()` function:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
ID_USER, 
NUMERO,
NOM
FROM USER_VIEW 
WHERE UPPER(NOM) = 'JACKSON'
ORDER BY nlssort(NUMERO, 'NLS_SORT=BINARY') ASC
/

   ID_USER NUMERO   NOM    
---------- -------- -------
         8 *04      JACKSON
         5 *15      JACKSON
         7 *61      JACKSON
         4 1999     JACKSON
         0 2001     JACKSON
         3 2006     JACKSON
         1 TI33     JACKSON
         9 TI99     JACKSON
```

but that still puts the `*` values first.

You might have to use a case expression to fix that:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
ID_USER, 
NUMERO,
NOM
FROM USER_VIEW 
WHERE UPPER(NOM) = 'JACKSON'
ORDER BY CASE WHEN SUBSTR(NUMERO, 1, 1) = '*' then 2 else 1 end, NUMERO
/

   ID_USER NUMERO   NOM    
---------- -------- -------
         1 TI33     JACKSON
         9 TI99     JACKSON
         4 1999     JACKSON
         0 2001     JACKSON
         3 2006     JACKSON
         8 *04      JACKSON
         5 *15      JACKSON
         7 *61      JACKSON
```

> I have a framework that append ASC or DESC to the custom query depending on a boutton in a GUI and I can't touch the framework to make it change values in the case expression also

Then you can concatenate the case expression result (as string rather than numbers, with any characters that are in the right order in your collation really); as you order by a single combined expression you can order that ascending:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
ID_USER, 
NUMERO,
NOM
FROM USER_VIEW 
WHERE UPPER(NOM) = 'JACKSON'
ORDER BY CASE WHEN SUBSTR(NUMERO, 1, 1) = '*' then 'B' else 'A' end || NUMERO ASC
/

   ID_USER NUMERO   NOM    
---------- -------- -------
         1 TI33     JACKSON
         9 TI99     JACKSON
         4 1999     JACKSON
         0 2001     JACKSON
         3 2006     JACKSON
         8 *04      JACKSON
         5 *15      JACKSON
         7 *61      JACKSON
```

... or descending:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
ID_USER, 
NUMERO,
NOM
FROM USER_VIEW 
WHERE UPPER(NOM) = 'JACKSON'
ORDER BY CASE WHEN SUBSTR(NUMERO, 1, 1) = '*' then 'B' else 'A' end || NUMERO DESC
/

   ID_USER NUMERO   NOM    
---------- -------- -------
         7 *61      JACKSON
         5 *15      JACKSON
         8 *04      JACKSON
         3 2006     JACKSON
         0 2001     JACKSON
         4 1999     JACKSON
         9 TI99     JACKSON
         1 TI33     JACKSON
```

Comment: the case expression partially fix the problem. Because if I want DESC order, I have to invert the 2 and 1, and that I can not do. The thing is, I have a framework that append ASC or DESC to the custom query depending on a boutton in a GUI and I can't touch the framework to make it change values in the case expression also.

Comment: @Aminos - I've added a version that ends up order by a single expression so it'll work with either ASC or DESC appended.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
select ID_USER, NUMERO, NOM 
from user_view
WHERE UPPER(NOM) = 'JACKSON'
order by replace(numero,'*','')
```